# Not able to reference object using hapi-swagger library

Tags: hapi-swagger

I am using hapi-swagger library 14.0.0. As per hapi-swagger library documentation used `options.deReference = true`. Still, I am not able to reference object.

Can anybody help me to solve the issue?

Expected behavior

```json
{
    "200": {
        "description": "a pet to be returned",
        "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
        }
    }
}
```

Getting

```json
{
    "200": {
        "description": "a pet to be returned",
        "schema": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```